# Deserialize JSON in Hack strict mode

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I have a nested JSON file, consisting of keys and values which are string only. But the structure of the JSON file is not fixed, so sometimes it could be nested 3 levels, sometimes only 2 levels.
I wonder how i could serialize this in strict mode?

```
  "live" : {
"host" : "localhost",
"somevalue" : "nothing",
"anobject" : {
  "one" : "two",
  "three" : "four",
  "five" : {
    "six" : "seven"
  }
}
```

}

If i would know the structure of the JSON, i simply would write my own class for it, but since the keys are not fixed, and also the nesting could be into several levels, i really wonder how i cut put such an object into a specific type.

Any help or hints appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `invariant`s will serve you well here. First off, it might be helpful to know that you can type a keyed tree strictly in Hack:

```php
<?hh // strict
class KeyedTree<+Tk as arraykey, +T> {
  public function __construct(
    private Map<Tk, KeyedTree<Tk, T>> $descendants = Map{},
    private ?T $v = null
  ) {}
}
```

<sup>(It must be a class because [cyclic shape definitions are sadly not allowed](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5594))</sup>

I haven't tried it yet, but `type_structure`s and [Fred Emmott's `TypeAssert`](https://fredemmott.co.uk/blog/posts/shapes-typeassert-and-json-apis) look to also be of interest. If some part of your JSON blob is known to be fixed, then you could isolate the nested, uncertain part and build a tree out of it with `invariant`s. In the limiting case where the whole blob is unknown, then you could excise the `TypeAssert` since there's no interesting fixed structure to assert:

```php
use FredEmmott\TypeAssert\TypeAssert;
class JSONParser {
    const type Blob = shape(
        'live' => shape(
            'host' => string, // fixed
            'somevalue' => string, // fixed
            'anobject' => KeyedTree<arraykey, mixed> // nested and uncertain
        )
    );
    public static function parse_json(string $json_str): this::Blob {
        $json = json_decode($json_str, true);
        invariant(!array_key_exists('anobject', $json), 'JSON is not properly formatted.');
        $json['anobject'] = self::DFS($json['anobject']);
          // replace the uncertain array with a `KeyedTree`
        return TypeAssert::matchesTypeStructure(
            type_structure(self::class, 'Blob'),
            $json
        );
        return $json;
    }
    public static function DFS(array<arraykey, mixed> $tree): KeyedTree<arraykey, mixed> {
        $descendants = Map{};
        foreach($tree as $k => $v) {
            if(is_array($v))
                $descendants[$k] = self::DFS($v);
            else
                $descendants[$k] = new KeyedTree(Map{}, $v); // leaf node
        }
        return new KeyedTree($descendants);
    }
}
```

Down the road, you'll still have to supplement `containsKey` invariants on the `KeyedTree`, but that's the reality with unstructured data in Hack.